# wordpress header problem / cant add open graph tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook, http-headers

i am trying to add the facebook open graph tags to my wordpress site
[woozybmx.com](http://woozybmx.com)

i tried several options but everytime i add them the facebook lint returns something like the tags would be placed outside the header and it cant read it.

can you help me? saying where exactly to place them in my header.php? i tried everything and it just doesnt work!

thanks!!!

Comment: In its current form this question isn't answerable. You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help you. Additionally, this site isn't the correct place to get help with this kind of problem. Either the [Worpress SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site ot [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) would be better suited for this.